# In SwiftUI how can I animate a button offset when displayed

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI, I want a button to appear from off screen by dropping in from the top into a final position when the view is initially displayed, I'm not asking for animation when the button is pressed.

I have tried:

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Button")
}.offset(x: 0.0, y: 100.0).animation(.basic(duration: 5))
```

but no joy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you would like to play with offset, this can get you started.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var offset: Length = 0

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) { Text("Button") }
            .offset(x: 0.0, y: offset)
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.basic(duration: 5)) { self.offset = 100.0 }
            }
    }
}
```

I first suggested a .transition(.move(.top)), but I am updating my answer. Unless your button is on the border of the screen, it may not be a good fit. The move is limited to the size of the moved view. So you may need to use offset after all!

Note that to make it start way out of the screen, the initial value of offset can be negative.

Answer (score 8):

First of all you need to create a transition. You could create an extension for `AnyTransition` or just create a variable. Use the `move()` modifier to tell the transition to move the view in from a specific edge

```swift
let transition = AnyTransition.move(edge: .top);
```

This alone only works if the view is at the edge of the screen. If your view is more towards the center you can use the `combined()` modifier to combine another transition such as `offset()` to add additional offset

```swift
let transition = AnyTransition
    .move(edge: .top)
    .combined(with:
        .offset(
            .init(width: 0, height: 100)
        )
    );
```

This transition will be for both showing and removing a view although you can use `AnyTransition.asymmetric()` to use different transitions for showing and removing a view

Next create a `showButton` bool (name this whatever) which will handle showing the button. This will use the `@State` property wrapper so SwiftUI will refresh the UI when changed.

```swift
@State var showButton: Bool = false;
```

Next you need to add the transition to your button and wrap your button within an `if` statement checking if the `showButton` bool is `true`

```swift
if (self.showButton == true) {
    Button(action: { }) {
        Text("Button")
    }
    .transition(transition);
}
```

Finally you can update the `showButton` bool to `true` or `false` within an animation block to animate the button transition. `toggle()` just reverses the state of the bool

```swift
withAnimation {
    self.showButton.toggle();
}
```

You can put your code in `onAppear()` and set the bool to `true` so the button is shown when the view appears. You can call `onAppear()` on most things like a `VStack`

```swift
.onAppear {
    withAnimation {
        self.showButton = true;
    }
}
```

Check the Apple docs to see what is available for `AnyTransition` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anytransition

Comment: Helpful! But why semicolons?

Comment: Helpful! But why brackets? -> if (self.showButton == true)

Comment: @Jessy It’s just a preference

Comment: @PeterKreinz It’s just a preference

Answer (score 3):

Presents a message box on top with animation:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MessageView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = -200.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Spacer()
                Text("Some message")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(Font.system(.headline).bold())
                Spacer()
            }.frame(height: 100)
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
                .offset(x: 0.0, y: self.offset)
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 1.5)) { self.offset = 000.0
                    }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this ends up animating the whole view, not just the message view

Answer (score 1):

For those that do want to start from a Button that moves when you tap on it, try this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var xLoc: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap me") {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2)) { self.xLoc+=50.0 }
        }.offset(x: xLoc, y: 0.0)
    }

}
```

Or alternatively (can replace Text with anything):

```
        Button(action: { 
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2)) { self.xLoc+=50.0 } 
            } )
        { Text("Tap me") }.offset(x: xLoc, y: 0.0)
```